# Некорректный вывод даты в js

Tags: javascript

Выводит почему-то ***11 июля 1932 г., 17:23:21***, как отображать текущую дату? Заранее спасибо!

```js
setTimeout(function run() {
  var m = new Date();
  var day = m.getDate();
  var month = m.getMonth();
  var year = m.getFullYear();

  var date = new Date(day, month, year, m.getHours(), m.getMinutes(), m.getSeconds());
  var options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  document.body.innerHTML = ("Сегодня  " + date.toLocaleString("ru", options));
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не к тому объекту использовал метод `.toLocaleString`.

Не

> data.toLocaleString(

а

> m.toLocaleString(

```js
setTimeout(function run() {
  var m = new Date();
  var day = m.getDate();
  var month = m.getMonth();
  var year = m.getFullYear();

  var date = new Date(day, month, year, m.getHours(), m.getMinutes(), m.getSeconds());
  var options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  document.body.innerHTML = ("Сегодня  " + m.toLocaleString("ru", options));
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```

Я не могу понять почему `setTimeout`, а не `setInterval`.
И использовать лишний вызов функции.

И зачем нужно объявлять два объекта `new Date()` ?

```js
setInterval(function run() {
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  document.body.innerHTML = ("Сегодня  " + date.toLocaleString("ru", options));

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Поздравляю с новым достижением `11.000`!

Comment: @Air "...не могу понять почему `setTimeout`, а не `setInterval`. И использовать лишний вызов функции". Думаю, что [поэтому](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#rekursivnyy-settimeout), и это правильно. Вопрос только в том, насколько это критично для ТС.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, благодарю...

Comment: @UModeL, в любом другом случае, ты прав... А с часами зачем это? Что дает?  На мой взгляд ничего....

Comment: @Air если это просто часы, то ничего не даёт. Если же эти часы будут управлять чем-то, возможно, что равномерность интервалов одно из условий. Хотя, я не исключаю избыточность из-за копипасты, без понимания матчасти :-)

Comment: @UModeL, красивое обвинение в некомпетентности... )))

Comment: @Air я не специально :) Просто, эта тема с таймерами мало где подробно разобрана.

Comment: @UModeL, в споре рождается истина.... ))) Ты высказываешься, я оппонирую... Потом в обратной последовательности... Я всегда рад конструктивное беседе... Ты меня переубедишь я буду рад, я тебя... Надеюсь ты будешь рад...  Век живи, век учись...

Answer (score 1):

Порядок параметров в `Date` идёт от большого к маленькому. `new Date(year, month, day)`

```js
setTimeout(function run() {
  var m = new Date();
  var day = m.getDate();
  var month = m.getMonth();
  var year = m.getFullYear();

  var date = new Date(year, month, day, m.getHours(), m.getMinutes(), m.getSeconds());
  var options = {
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    timezone: 'UTC',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric'
  };
  document.body.innerHTML = ("Сегодня  " + date.toLocaleString("ru", options));
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```